# Writing draggable elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can you write on this draggable element? Means if I double click the dragging widget it then text starts to get edit and write text in it.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the plugin [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) which does what you need i think. You could also try to combine both things